# R: str() gives unusual return, using igraph

Tags: r, string, igraph

I'm running R 3.3.3 with igraph, and keep seeing an odd return from str() when I pass a graph through it:

```
> g<-graph.formula(1-2,2-3,3-1)
> str(g)
List of 10
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ 1:Class 'igraph.vs'  atomic [1:2] 2 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "9ed96421-95d9-11e7-8000-010000000000"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ 2:Class 'igraph.vs'  atomic [1:2] 1 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "9ed96421-95d9-11e7-8000-010000000000"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ 3:Class 'igraph.vs'  atomic [1:2] 1 2
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "9ed96421-95d9-11e7-8000-010000000000"
 $ :Error in adjacent_vertices(x, i, mode = if (directed) "out" else "all") : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

I'm using Statistical Analysis of Network Data (Kolaczyk), and they seem to get a different return from str():

```
> g <- graph.formula(1-2, 1-3, 2-3, 2-4, 3-5, 4-5, 4-6,4-7, 5-6, 6-7)
> str(g)
IGRAPH UN-- 7 10 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
1 -- 2, 3
2 -- 1, 3, 4
3 -- 1, 2, 5
4 -- 2, 5, 6, 7
5 -- 3, 4, 6
6 -- 4, 5, 7
7 -- 4, 6
```

The above code snippet is taken from: https://github.com/kolaczyk/sand/blob/master/sand/inst/code/chapter2.R. I'm wondering why my return is not in the same format, and if there's anything I can do to get my output to look like the second. I've tried a few versions of R (3.4.1,3.3.2, 3.3.3), and still see the same thing. My guess is that this is coming from igraph rather than R, but I'm not sure - any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce this on igraph v1.1.2 , but previous installed version has the other outcome .

Comment: ah looking at `?str.igraph` it says "As of igraph 1.1.1, the `str.igraph` function is defunct, use `print_all()`." So use `print_all(g)`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by user20650, the error is due to the fact that the user is calling a defunct function.

substitute in your code

```
str(g)
```

with

```
print_all(g)
```

This works for the older training material, either Luke's or Kolaczyk's, from Springer.